# WCF and XML Serializable issue

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I'm recieving an error in Traceviewer "To be XML serializable, types which inherit from IEnumerable must have an implementation of Add(System.Object) at all levels of their inheritance hierarchy. MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader does not implement Add(System.Object)."

I'm writing a WCF service that a sql query can be passed to it and will run the query.  Any idea what this error means? How to resolve the issue as well.

This service is running Mysql Connector/Net as well

Comment: The error seems pretty clear to me - `MySqlDataReader` doesn't implement `Add(System.Object)`.  You might consider posting the code for the object you're trying to serialize, maybe there's another way to accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: well of course....how can it get corrected?

Comment: Iterate through all the rows in the MySqlDataReader, read each column, create a suitable new class that has 1 property per column, add those to a list, return that to WCF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was passing the object through the wcf service.  For whatever reason it didn't like it so I've outputted the data to an array and sent that across.  That worked.